# What is the concavity of a velocity graph given a distance graph?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

[image: A distance vs time graph that is concave down and increasing]

Given a concave down increasing distance vs time graph, can we learn anything about the concavity of the velocity vs time graph?
I know that the concavity of a function is the same as the sign of the second derivative but I don't see how we can tell the concavity of the derivative with just a graph.

Comment: The concavity of the velocity vs time graph depends on the sign of the third derivative of your position graph - this much should be clear so far.

Comment: I understand that but I don't see a way to determine the third derivative visually. We aren't given any numerical values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The velocity vs time function is completely determined by the graph of position vs time, via differentiation. So yes, technically all of the information is there to determine it.

The first thing to notice is that all different combinations of concavity of position and velocity vs time are possible. That is, if all we know is $f''<0$, it can't tell us that $f'''<0$ or $f'''>0$ or $f''' = 0$.

So, as you said, the best way to figure it out, will simply be to derive the velocity graph and check its concavity.

Comment: My problem is that in a graph like the one I was given, we are not given any numerical values.

Comment: Can you visualize the velocity curve for that graph?

Comment: The only thing that is obvious to me is that it is decreasing and positive.

Comment: Exactly! It starts high and positive, then tends towards 0. So the velocity vs time curve in your example is concave up.

Comment: The tends towards zero part is what I don't fully understand. How do we know that it is not a linear line. Is it because there seems to be an asymptote where the velocity approaches zero but never does?
Thank you for your help

Comment: That is correct, if the velocity is literally 0, then it is not concave either which way. In the case of your graph, there is no horizontal flatline, so the second derivative of the velocity looks always positive to me

Comment: "Life is about avoiding losing": The velocity graph is not concave down. (Since $v\ge 0$, and $v$ is decreasing) "Life is about winning": The velocity is concave up. (Since there is clearly an asymptote, $v > 0$ and is decreasing).